# Selecting child view at index using Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

With Espresso when using a custom widget view with child image views, which Matcher type can I use to select the nth child?
Example:

```
+--------->NumberSlider{id=2131296844, res-name=number_slider, visibility=VISIBLE, width=700, height=95, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=10.0, y=0.0, child-count=7}
|
+---------->NumberView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=99, height=95, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+---------->NumberView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=100, height=95, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=99.0, y=0.0}
|
+---------->NumberView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=100, height=95, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=199.0, y=0.0}
|
+---------->NumberView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=100, height=95, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=299.0, y=0.0}
|
+---------->NumberView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=100, height=95, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=399.0, y=0.0}
|
+---------->NumberView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=100, height=95, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=499.0, y=0.0}
|
+---------->NumberView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=100, height=95, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=599.0, y=0.0}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
 public static Matcher<View> nthChildOf(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int childPosition) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
      @Override
      public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with "+childPosition+" child view of type parentMatcher");
      }

      @Override
      public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
        if (!(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) {
          return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent());
        }

        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent()) && group.getChildAt(childPosition).equals(view);
      }
    };
  }
```

To use it

```
onView(nthChildOf(withId(R.id.parent_container), 0)).check(matches(withText("I am the first child")));
```

Comment: It would be safer to use `return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent()) && view.equals(group.getChildAt(childPosition))` in the last instruction to avoid a NullPointerException if there is not enough child views in the parent

Answer (score 27):

To try and improve a little on Maragues's solution, I've made a few changes.

The solution is to create a custom *Matcher<View>* that wraps another *Matcher<View>* for the parent view, and takes the index of the child view to be matched.

```
public static Matcher<View> nthChildOf(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int childPosition) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("position " + childPosition + " of parent ");
            parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if (!(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) return false;
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

            return parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                    && parent.getChildCount() > childPosition
                    && parent.getChildAt(childPosition).equals(view);
        }
    };
}
```

**Detailed Explanation**

You can override the *describeTo* method in order to give an easy to understand description of the matcher by appending to the *Description* argument. You'll also want to propagate the *describeTo* call to the parent matcher so it's description also gets added.

```
@Override
public void describeTo(Description description) {
    description.appendText("position " + childPosition + " of parent "); // Add this matcher's description.
    parentMatcher.describeTo(description); // Add the parentMatcher description.
}
```

Next, you should override *matchesSafely* which will determine when a match in the view hierarchy has been found. When called with a view whose parent matches the provided parent matcher, check that the view is equal to the child at the provided position.

If the parent doesn't have a *childCount* greater than the child position, *getChildAt* will return null and cause the test to crash. It's better to avoid crashing and allow the test to fail so that we get a proper test report and error message.

```
@Override
public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
if (!(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) return false; // If it's not a ViewGroup we know it doesn't match.
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

    return parentMatcher.matches(parent) // Check that the parent matches.
            && parent.getChildCount() > childPosition // Make sure there's enough children.
            && parent.getChildAt(childPosition).equals(view); // Check that this is the right child.
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you for the very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 12):

If you can get the parent view. May be [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-test-kit-discuss/E9R6jk46AOQ) which defined a matcher to get the first child of a view can give you some clue.

```
     public static Matcher<View> firstChildOf(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with first child view of type parentMatcher");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {       

                if (!(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) {
                    return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent());                   
                }
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent()) && group.getChildAt(0).equals(view);

            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: If you need to get the nth, it should be use getChildAt(n).

Comment: It works for me. Thanks. I propose an improvement to reuse the solution, using an matcher called isChildOfAtPosition(@IdRes parentId: Int, position: Int)


https://gist.github.com/luisfernandezbr/a3e3bbf0cb00e9584bf896b379bdafd3

Answer (score 9):

While the answers in this thread do work, I just wanted to point out that it is possible to get a handle on a particular child of a particular view without having to define a new `Matcher` class.

You can do so by joining up the view matchers offered by Espresso into a method as follows:

```
/**
 * @param parentViewId the resource id of the parent [View].
 * @param position the child index of the [View] to match.
 * @return a [Matcher] that matches the child [View] which has the given [position] within the specified parent.
 */
fun withPositionInParent(parentViewId: Int, position: Int): Matcher<View> {
    return allOf(withParent(withId(parentViewId)), withParentIndex(position))
}
```

You will call on this method as follows:

```
onView(
    withPositionInParent(R.id.parent, 0)
).check(
    matches(withId(R.id.child))
)
```

Comment: Of the solutions posted, this one is the most elegant. Thank you!

Comment: Beautiful solution! Thanks a lot!