# Testing ViewPager with Espresso. How perfom action to a button of an Item?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-espresso, ui-testing

I have a `ViewPager` whith items containing only a picture and a button.

I can't successfully interact with the UI of an item (Page) because, except the displayed picture, there is nothing to differentiate (from UI point of view) all items of the `ViewPager`.

I tried to select only one item with a position:

```
onData(is(instanceOf(ItemClass.class)))
            .atPosition(0)
            .onChildView(withId(R.id.button))
            .perform(click());
```

causing:

> NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView

**How to access and test items of a `ViewPager` with Espresso ?**

Answer (score 109, accepted):

FirstVal, `ViewPager` is not an `AdapterView`, it directly extends from `ViewGroup`. So the method `onData()` **cannot** be used on a `ViewPager`.

### Solution 1

As it's a `ViewGroup`, each items are direct children of its `ViewPager`.
So the process is to reference the first view child using a custom matcher (like this one[`firstChildOf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748303/selecting-child-view-at-index-using-espresso/24933287#24933287)) and playing with [`hasDescendant()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#hasDescendant(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Candroid.view.View%3E)) and [`isDescendantOfA()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#isDescendantOfA(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Candroid.view.View%3E)) to access the targeted view and perform an  action on it.

```
 onView(allOf(withId(R.id.button), isDescendantOfA(firstChildOf(withId(R.id.viewpager)))))
            .perform(click());
```

---

### Solution 2 (da best)

As the particularity of the `ViewPager` is to display each items (#1 solution's child views) that composed it, one by one (page-by-page style). So even if your items use the same layout with the same IDs, only one is displayed. So we can reference the targeted view by its Id and add the constraints [`isDisplayed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#isDisplayed()). It will match only one view, the one that is currently displayed.

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.button), isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

as simple as that.

And if you want another item, you may perform a [`swipe()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#swipeDown()) on your `ViewPager` to change the displayed item:

```
onView(withId(R.id.viewpager)).perform(swipeLeft());
```

---

Notes from the [Android dev doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#isDisplayed()):

> isDisplayed will select views that are partially displayed (eg:
> the full height/width of the view is greater than the height/width of
> the visible rectangle). If you wish to ensure the entire rectangle
> this view draws is displayed to the user use [isCompletelyDisplayed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers#isCompletelyDisplayed())

Thanks @TWiStErRob

Comment: You might want to use `isCompletelyDisplayed()`. In my experience `isDisplayed()` also matches views in off-screen pages.

Comment: @TWiStErRob has given an awesome tip, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33516360/6373011

Comment: can you add position in this, as all the list is having same ids...onView(allOf(withId(R.id.button), isDisplayed())).perform(click());

Comment: I had similar issues with a ViewPager which used the same view but with different items. Where as @TWiStErRob mentioned ```isDisplayed()``` matched off-screen views. So I tried ```isCompletelyDisplayed()``` but as I was swiping just before the check, even with animations turned off, Espresso doesn't seem to manage that. So what I ended up doing was using:

```onView(allOf(withId(R.id.recyclerView), isDisplayingAtLeast(60)))```

And the recycler view is now correctly identified all the time.