# Android-Espresso: Can't get element in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

We have a View Pager in our app that when a user is signed out we show the same UI. So since the UI is the same for each page on the view pager tapping on an element or checking if it is displayed just gives me the Matches multiple error. So my theory is since view pagers load everything at once that is why i get this error. Changing the contentDescriptor doesn't work since it will be the same in all views.

The view is of a button when not signed in and when signed in it will have a grid view.

So my question is - how do I get to the button or whatever element I may need? I cannot change the app code.

Using Espresso 2.2.2

Comment: Use the custom Matcher<View> seen in this stack overflow post http://stackoverflow.com/a/30073528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that the `ViewPager` creates at least the `View` to the left and right of the currently visible `View`. And Espresso uses all matchers in `onView` on every `View` in the hierarchy, regardless if it is on the screen or not.

If just one of the `Views` you want to match is currently visible, then use  `isDisplayed` to match the `View` that is currently on the screen:

```
// Matches a view that is on the screen AND has the id R.id.some_button
onView(allOf(isDisplayed(), withId(R.string.some_id))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

If you do not `check()` or `perform()` after you have matched a `View` with `onView()` the test will *not* fail! So if you want to check if a `View` is visible, then you have to `check(matches(isDisplayed()))` too.