# Espresso: how to get the children of a View by index

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a view containing EditText and I want to be sure that they are displayed in the correct order. I use Espresso but I don't know how to get the children of a view by index. Is it a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35899479/1827254).
The idea is to create a new Matcher.
Is it a better way to do that, directly with Espresso without to create a Matcher?

```
public static Matcher<View> nthChildOf(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int childPosition) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("position " + childPosition + " of parent ");
            parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if (!(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) return false;
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

            return parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                    && parent.getChildCount() > childPosition
                    && parent.getChildAt(childPosition).equals(view);
        }
    };
}
```